# R 'longitudinal' package - exporting shrinkage objects

Tags: r, export

I am working with multivariate longitudinal data, and was hoping to use the 'longitudinal' package to look at dynamical correlation between variables. I have been able to run the code fine until the end:

[example using stored data from the package]:

```
library("longitudinal")
data(tcell)
dynpc <- dyn.pcor(tcell.34, lambda=0)
class(dynpc)
```

(object is of class"shrinkage")

So here is my problem: how do I export this data to a .txt or .csv file? The function gives me a matrix of correlations, along with other information.

Comment: Which part of the data ? if you want to export correlation matrix just do `write.csv(dynpc, "dynpc.csv")` (or `write.table` if you prefer)

Comment: Thank you! For some reason the first time I tried that it wouldn't coerce the file, but I tried it now and it's fine.